# prevent changing access levels of inherited protected members

Tags: c++, oop

Is there a way to prevent someone from changing access level of inherited protected member?
Someone can use a `using` declaration in derived class and increase access level of inherited protected member to public.

Now the question is how to prevent this?

**example:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
 protected:
   int i(){};
 };

class B : public A {
 public:
   using A::i;
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.i();
  return 0;
}
```

**How to Prevent**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
 private:
   void i(int) {};
 protected:
   int i(){};
 };

class B : public A {
 public:
   using A::i;
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.i();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Everyone can access protected fields just fine, so why would you want to even do that?

Comment: If everyone can access them, then why they exist?

Comment: @hamed: They exist to prevent *accidental* breaches of encapsulation. There's no way to prevent *deliberate* breaches like this, even if you wanted to, and so there's no point in just preventing the most straightforward way to do that.

Comment: @hamed Your "How to prevent" section is wrong. You can't have two members with the same name `A::i` and `A::i()`. Even without `using A::i`...

Comment: you're right, this can only works with member function only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. Even if you could prevent the `using` directive, derived classes can still simply expose a new public field that is a pointer or reference to the protected member, or a public member function that returns such a pointer or reference.

Comment: finally I found that if I define a dummy private method named `i`, then derived class can't use `using A::i;`.

Comment: @hamed Your `class A` won't compile event without `class B` in your "How to prevent" example... You can't have two members with the same name...

Comment: `class B : public A { public: void i() { A::i(); } };` As you can see - in case of methods - you can just promote without using `using` ...